# Improper integrals through partitions of unity (Problem 3-37 from Spivak)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, manifolds, improper-integrals

Below is Problem 3-37 from Spivak's "Calculus on Manifolds". I don't know how to approach it. To begin with, I don't even understand which admissible cover should I take and which partition of unity should I take (why I need to choose these things is explained in the definition below).

> (a) Suppose that $f: (0,1)\to R$ is a nonnegative continuous function.
>   Show that $\int_{(0,1)}f$ exists iff $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}
> > \int_\epsilon^{1-\epsilon} f$ exists.
>
> (b) Let $A_n=[1-1/2^n,1-1/2^{n+1}]$. Suppose that $f: (0,1)\to R$
>   satisfies $\int_{A_n}f=(-1)^n/n$ and $f=0$ for $x\notin$ any $A_n$.
>   Show that $\int_{(0,1)}f$ does not exist, but $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}
> > \int_{(\epsilon,1-\epsilon)}f=\log 2$. (Note: errata says that one
>   must require an additional assumption, e.g.: on each $A_n$, $f$ is
>   either positive or negative, but not both.)

Also note that the integrals of the form $\int_{(a,b)}g$ are understood in "the extended sense" (please see the definition at the bottom of the following text:

[image]

Comment: This is too long of a question.  I showed you how to do part (a).  If you can't now finish part (b), then ask as a separate question and show some work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Without partition of unity**

You can avoid the partition-of-unity formalism to prove (a). The extended integral of a nonnegative continuous function on an open interval in $\mathbb{R}$ (or more generally open rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^n$) can be defined equivalently as

$$\int_{(0,1)} f = \sup_{D \subset (0,1)} \int_D f,$$

if the supremum taken over all compact subsets of $(0,1)$ is finite.

If the extended integral exists then for the compact interval $[\epsilon,1-\epsilon]$ we have

$$\tag{1}\int_\epsilon^{1 - \epsilon}f \leqslant \sup_{D \subset (0,1)} \int_D f = \int_{(0,1)} f.$$

Since the integral on the LHS of (1) is bounded and increasing as $\epsilon \to 0$ it follows that

$$\tag{2} \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_\epsilon^{1 - \epsilon}f \leqslant \int_{(0,1)}f$$

Conversely, if the limit on the LHS of (2) exists, then the integral over $I_\epsilon = [\epsilon,1-\epsilon]$ is bounded for all $\epsilon$ such that $I_\epsilon \subset (0,1)$. For any compact $D \subset (0,1)$, the collection $\{I_\epsilon\}$ is an open cover and there exists $\epsilon'$ such that $D \subset I_{\epsilon'}$and we have

$$\int_Df \leqslant \int_{\epsilon'}^{1 - \epsilon'} f \leqslant \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_\epsilon^{1 - \epsilon} f.$$

Thus,

$$\int_{(0,1} f = \sup_{D \subset (0,1)}f \leqslant \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_\epsilon^{1 - \epsilon} f.$$

**With partition of unity**

Let $\mathcal{O}$ be an admissible open cover  of $(0,1)$ and $\Phi$  be a subordinate partition of unity.

The proof relies heavily on the basic property that $\sum_{\phi \in \Phi} \phi(x) = 1$ for all $x \in (0,1).$

We have $\phi(x) \neq 0$ for only finitely many $\phi \in \Phi$ on the compact interval $\epsilon,1-\epsilon]$. Thus,

$$\tag{3}\int_\epsilon^{1 - \epsilon} f  = \int_\epsilon^{1-\epsilon} \left(\sum_{\phi \in \Phi} \phi\right) \, f =  \sum_{\phi \in \Phi} \int_\epsilon^{1-\epsilon} \phi \, f \leqslant \sum_{\phi \in \Phi} \int_{(0,1)} \phi \, f   .$$

If the RHS of (3) converges and $\int_{(0,1)}f$ exists, then the limit of the LHS as $\epsilon \to 0$ exists since $\int_\epsilon^{1-\epsilon} f $ is bounded and increasing (for $f$ nonnegative).

On the other hand, suppose $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_\epsilon^{1 - \epsilon} f$ exists.  By the properties of a partition of unity, for finitely many $\phi_1 , \ldots, \phi_n$, there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $\phi_k(x) = 0$ for $1 \leqslant k \leqslant n$ when $x \notin [\epsilon, 1 - \epsilon]$. Thus,

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \int_{(0,1)} \phi_k \, f = \sum_{k=1}^n \int_{\epsilon}^{1-\epsilon} \phi_k \, f = \int_{\epsilon}^{1-\epsilon} \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \phi_k\right) \, f = \int_\epsilon^{1-\epsilon}f \leqslant \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_\epsilon^{1-\epsilon} f$$

Hence, the limit of the LHS as $n \to \infty$ exists since the sum is bounded and increasing and, therefore,  $\int_{(0,1)} f $ exists.

Comment: Thank you. I'm confused with the equality in the last display -- why does it hold?

Comment: @user531299:  That is how the partition of unity is supposed to work (developed in the chapter preceding the problem).  Every point  $x \in (0,1)$ has a neighborhood that intersects the support sets of only a finite number of the continuous $\phi$ functions. Furthermore, $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \phi_k(x) = 1$.

Comment: Let me rewrite this in a better way.

Comment: I am confused as to why, in the second implication, there must exist such epsilon. It seems to me, this is because A is bounded, and the cover is admissible, meaning the partitions of unity are actually compactly supported, but it doesn’t seem trivial to me to conclude this without these considerations, since it is not only a consequence of the properties of p.o.u. but the topology of the set. Do you agree? Thanks